# Changing D3.js input format from .csv to an array of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a d3.js histogram on my website which is getting the data from a solr response. On my research I discovered [Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock) who's offering great D3 solutions. One of it is the "[Histogram II](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b2fee5dae98555cf78c9e4c5074b87c3)"  which would fit perfectly for my needs. The problem is that it (and all other comparable solutions I found) comes with a .csv as data source. I would like to use an array as data source but failed as I tried to change the input.

Can you please give me a tip which lines have to be changed to use the following array, which is currently based on Mike Bostocks .csv:

```
my_data = [
    {"id": "10097071", "case": "HY285524", "date": "06/02/2015 09:41:19 PM"},
    {"id": "21907", "case": "HY291065", "date": "06/07/2015 03:50:00 AM"}
  ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit: Gerados questions is gone. He asked if I'm parsing the dates.

@GerardoFurtado I avoided to fully copy Mike Bostocks code. If Iinterpret it correctly the dates get parsed by "d3.timeParse("%m/%d/ ...)" in his solution. I'm struggeling with his line 'd3.csv("homicides.csv", type, function(error, data)' where I'm not able to say "use the array instead".

Comment: I deleted my comment because I thought it was obvious that you were parsing the dates. Now I see you aren't parsing the dates: that `parseDate` variable simply defines the specifier. In Bostock's code, the dates are being parsed in the accessor (row) function. However, there is no accessor function if you're using a variable to store the data. That being said, you have to use a `forEach` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bostock's original code, the `date` strings are being parsed by the `type` function, called by `d3.csv` as a row function:

```
function type(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    return d;
}
```

Since you plan to use an variable to hold your data array and get rid of `d3.csv` completely, you'll have to parse the `date` strings some other way. For instance, you can use a `forEach`:

```
data.forEach(function(d){
  d.date = parseDate(d.date)
})
```

Here is the demo, I just modified Bostock's code for using an array instead of a CSV file: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/bb0d820fbca8fbdf0f8827b0edbcbd44. Look at the `forEach` after the `data` array.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you! :)  For a test I copy-pasted it and it works fine. Of course I will reconstruct your solution to get a deeper understanding.